# How to build Spring Statemachine with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-statemachine

I downloaded Spring Statemachine (ZIP)

I don't have any a pom.xml/maven instruction

In [site] the maven link isn't available  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Downloading-Spring-artifacts

> for Maven repository information.

How should I build project with maven ?

Comment: see here: https://projects.spring.io/spring-statemachine/#quick-start (don't need to "download" it, just add a dependency to your (existing) maven project).

Comment: ..and their github (no wiki) is at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine

Comment: @xerx593 I want the source ,not just as dependency

Comment: source -> https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine ..respectively at: http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/statemachine/spring-statemachine-core/ ..<RELEASE>/*sources.jar

Comment: @xerx593 thanks, but it seems that I still missing dependencies as, e.g. Spring boot for `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: @xerx593 Also other dependenies as spring-context

Comment: "spring boot quickstart" ;)

Comment: Did you really missed the "Build from source" section in the official doc? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine#building-from-source You should build with gradle

Answer (score 0):

Its gradle project.. You can make use of gradle to build it.

**Gradle to Maven:**

Add Maven plugin in the build.gradle file.

build.gradle should look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.abc.app'
// artifactId is taken by default, from folder name
version = '0.1-SNAPSHOT'

dependencies {
compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.3'
}
```

Run gradle install in the directory containing build.gradle will do the job.

It will create pom-default.xml in the build/poms subfolder.

***Reference links for Gradle Build:***

https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds/

https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2018/february/buildship.php

https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle/

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html

Comment: I currently don't use gradle, how can I work with maven?

Comment: So you mean to convert gradle build to maven build??

Comment: convert or build releavant pom.xml for this project

Comment: I get pom with `commons-lang` only and not all relevant dependencies